# animated sprite won't stop animation - cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, animated

I have an animated sprite using two pngs. The animation works fine. I have another method that is run when the game is over.

```
 //Grey mouse with Pompom
greyMousePomPom = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pink_mice_pom_anime_01.png"];
greyMousePomPom.tag=132;
[self addChild:greyMousePomPom z:6];
greyMousePomPom.position = CGPointMake(550, 70); 

//Grey Pom Pom Mouse animation
CCAnimation *greyMousePomPomAnimate = [CCAnimation animation];
[greyMousePomPomAnimate addFrameWithFilename:@"gray_mice_pom_anime_01.png"];
[greyMousePomPomAnimate addFrameWithFilename:@"gray_mice_pom_anime_02.png"];
id greyMousePopPomAnimationAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:1.3f animation:greyMousePomPomAnimate restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

repeatAnimationPomPom2 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:greyMousePopPomAnimationAction];
[greyMousePomPom runAction:repeatAnimationPomPom2];
```

When I run my method to change the animated sprites texture and to stop them the animation continues behind the new texture.

```
-(void) changePomPomMiceToSadFaceForFreeFall
```

{
    NSLog(@"making the mice sad");

```
[self stopAllActions];


[greyMousePomPom setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"gray_mice_pom_anime_03.png"]];
```

}

I know this method is working because it is NSLogging and the textures are changing. But why aren't the animations stopping? I have tried to remove it by tag and by declaring the action but no success.

I know there are a lot of people out there that are smarter than me.. can you help?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing right now is stop all animations added to the current node:

```
self
```

If you added any action to self, this command would be perfectly fine to stop all of them.

Instead what you need to do is, you need to call the `stopAllActions` method on the object you added the actions to:

```
[greyMousePomPom stopAllActions];
```

HTH

Comment: thanks for the answer HTH. sadly i tried that with no luck either. I can do everything within the original method (make the sprites invisible etc) but in another method using ivars i have no luck. booooo